# Converting string to date with Velocity Template Language in Liferay 6 GA2

Tags: date, velocity, liferay-6, liferay-velocity, web-content

I'm having trouble converting a string to a date object in a Liferay 6 GA2 web content template.

I've tried my hand using the tools available ( [Access Objects in Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Access+Objects+from+Velocity) )

I've even tried importing Java classes like:

```
#set ($foo = "2012-12-06")
#set ($bar = $portal.getClass().forName('java.text.SimpleDateFormat'))
$bar.parse($foo)
```

Nothing has worked so far.  Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

```
#set($foo="20121206")
#set($format=$dateUtil.getISOFormat($foo))
$format.parse($foo)
```

Comment: where and how is $dateUtil defined?